# Совершение HTTP запроса

Tags: angularjs

Пытаюсь загрузить .json файл

```
<div ng-controller="articleController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="article in articles">
      <b>{{article.title}}</b>
      <p>{{article.text}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('articleController', function($scope) {

    /*
        $scope.articles = [{
            title: 'Nokia Lumia 630',
            text: 2014
        },{
            title: 'Samsung Galaxy S 4',
            text: 2014
        },{
            title: 'Mi 5',
            text: 2015
        }]
        */

        $http.get('articles.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.articles = data;
        });

    });
</script>
```

На том что закомментированно работает отлично. Помещаю в файл articles.json эти данные и пытаюсь загрузить, ничего не происходит, в чем дело?

Comment: Предположу, что 'articles.json' содержит неверный формат или в ответе не то, что ты ожидаешь. Попробуй вывести в консоль ответ сервера - должно навести на мысль, что не так. `$http.get('articles.json').success(function(data){ console.log(data); // -> [Object object] console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); $scope.articles = data; });`

Comment: Вывел в консольку [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ge8xxoodfcreddo/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Строку `angular.module('myApp', []).controller('articleController', function($scope) {`
переппеши как  `angular.module('myApp', []).controller(', function($scope, $http) {`

На скрине видно, что `$http` не доступен в контроллере.

Comment: Опять ошибочка. [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rei2kfakifl4y6u/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA1.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Думаю, тебе нужен веб-сервер. Посмотри на https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Павел, если в ответе нет решения, то не стоит отмечать его как верный (галочкой). Это будет запутывать будущих читателей.